# How can I get parent guid of an item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, api, microsoft-graph, guid

I have a list with items in SharePoint Online. There many items and their structure look like a tree.

```
list/
    itemA/
    itemB/
          itemBa/
                 itemX
          itemBb/
                 itemY
          itemBc/
    itemC/
```

How can I get a parent guid of the itemX by REST or GraphAPI? (for example)

Actually, I have to get a hierarchy of items on the List.
But SharePoint API provides children of a List, but not their hierarchy. Is it possible to get?

Answer (score 0):

For Item-

_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items(1)/ParentID

For Site-

_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl/_api/web/parentweb?$select=Id

Comment: It doesn't work.

{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Cannot find resource for the request ParentID."
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to get the parent folder's GUID. You will require 2 calls to do so:

1. Use below REST API to access the actual item. In that you will have file directory reference. This will be used to access your parent folder of item. i.e.: `itemX`

   `https://<site-url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list-title>')/items(<item-id>)?$select=ID,FileDirRef`

In the output: you will have relative path of the parent folder. Use that path in 2nd step.

2. Create REST API to access GUID of the parent folder as below:

`https://<site-url>/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<pass the relative path of the parent folder>')/listitemallfields/GUID`

output:

> <d:GUID
> xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
> xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
> xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
> xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
> m:type="Edm.Guid">70870a3f-2f73-4ad9-b5ac-8eeba2d823b0</d:GUID>

Comment: It returns the item properties.

Comment: But I need a parent GUID of the item

Comment: Please check my updated answer to get parent folder's GUID.

Comment: Yes, it should work. But I prefer to use one request. Because there Throttling limits

Comment: In that case, you can get all the items from list with their directory path & GUID. Then manipulate them within json array to identify the guid of the parent of your item. Because there is no such API I found that gives parent GUID details during actual item fetch.

Comment: It's very sad (:

Comment: Do you know why Sharepoint doesn't provide a parent guid of an item?